# How can I temporarily move my value to something other than bitcoin without providing identifiaction?

Tags: exchanges

Bitcoin is in a bubble right now, I would like to sell them as I believe the value will drop within a couple of days. I tried registering an account on mtgox, but it's complicated and they seem to have some problem to keep up with registrations(my account isn't confirmed yet)

I want to sell my bitcoins so I can trade them back. I looked at litecoin, wich seems like a nice option, but their value has also gone up a lot the last couple of days, relative to bitcoins. Are there any other options available?

Answer (score 2):

http://campbx.com is another exchange; I believe no customer verification is required until you want to move USD in or out.  If you just want to sell bitcoins and plan to buy them back later, I don't think ID would be needed.

Answer (score 1):

Try https://localbitcoins.com/.  You also may want to trade your bitcoins for various in-game currencies for which exchanges exist.  These exchanges usually don't require you to have a game account in order to trade in the currencies.  You also might want to try exchanges that deal in other fiat currencies (i.e. Euros) that may not require you to identify yourself or have a bank account, as long as you are willing to let your fiat sit in the exchange without withdrawing it or only use it to buy bitcoin later.